# Ionic 3 httpClient for Http Module

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm following this [Tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-data-driven-quiz-app-in-ionic-2-part-2/) for my Ionic app. This using **http** Module.But now angular 4+ has **httpClient**. I have done some changes according to that. Now app is working fine until I start. When I restart the app it shows the error

*Property 'questions' does not exist on type 'Object'.*

but again when I hit ctrl+s and save changes error is disappeared. How can I fix this??

Json is

```
 {
    "questions": [

        {
            "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/imgs/helicopter.png' />",
            "flashCardBack": "Helicopter",
            "flashCardFlipped": false,
            "questionText": "What is this?",
            "answers": [
                {"answer": "Helicopter", "correct": true, "selected": false},
                {"answer": "Plane", "correct": false, "selected": false},
                {"answer": "Truck", "correct": false, "selected": false}
            ]
        },
        {
            "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/imgs/plane.png' />",
            "flashCardBack": "Plane",
            "flashCardFlipped": false,
            "questionText": "What is this?",
            "answers": [
                {"answer": "Helicopter", "correct": false, "selected": false},
                {"answer": "Plane", "correct": true, "selected": false},
                {"answer": "Truck", "correct": false, "selected": false}
            ]
        },
        {
            "flashCardFront": "<img src='assets/imgs/truck.png' />",
            "flashCardBack": "Truck",
            "flashCardFlipped": false,
            "questionText": "What is this?",
            "answers": [
                {"answer": "Helicopter", "correct": false, "selected": false},
                {"answer": "Plane", "correct": false, "selected": false},
                {"answer": "Truck", "correct": true, "selected": false}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my code in provider using **httpClient**

```
load() {
    if(this.data) {
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('assets/data/questions.json').subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data.questions; //error here
            resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
 }
```

Comment: Can you add the json to the question ?

Comment: @Anuradha Gunasekara  done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `any` type to your `data` on `.subscribe` like so:

```
load() {
    if(this.data) {
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('assets/data/questions.json').subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.data = data.questions;
            resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Fixed the problem using the answer

Answer (score 2):

Hi you have to add latest http into your project [FIDDLE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-client-example?file=pages/home/home.ts)

```
npm install @angular/http@latest --save
```

Next, open and edit 'src/app/app.module.ts' then add this import.

```
imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   HttpClientModule,
   IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
```

Next add http into your .ts file

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

create variable in constructor

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
     console.log('Hello RestServiceProvider Provider');
}
```

Then use it

```
load() {
  if(this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data //error here
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
          resolve(this.data);
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: I know  need to add a constructor to use any module

Comment: Check the fiddle demo and you can just replace your file and check it will work for you or not

Comment: `npm install @angular/http@latest --save` not required at all see from which package you are importing `HttpClient` -> `'@angular/common/http';`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing the key point which is `.map(res => res.json())` and then `.subscripe` the data.

```
this.http.get('assets/data/questions.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
       this.data = data.questions;
       resolve(this.data);
});
```

I think, Since the response contains `json object` and which has `questions: []` array, but this piece of code tries to access one level before `this.data = data.questions;` which is not mapped yet.

Hope this helps.,

Comment: Nope in `HttpClientModule` response object is a JSON by default, so there's no need to parse it anymore.